# return false only works when the answer is correct?

Tags: jquery

There are two numbers. User fills out answer & clicks enter or the "next" button (activate form)

I want the form to always "return false" as all next actions are loaded with javascript.
As long as the user keeps filling out the correct answer it works, but when you fill out the wrong answer, it first shows you the "hey you, what is this?" box, but twhen user tries to answer again, the entire page is realoaded :/

You can see it here:
http://skolresurser.se/matematik/simple/

HTML

```
<form id="theChallenge">
    <h1>
        <span class="first">2</span>
        <span style="position: relative; top: 0.24em; margin: 0 6px;">*</span>
        <span class="second">6</span>
        <span style="margin-left: 0.13em; font-size: 0.8em; position: relative; top: -0.13em; margin-right: -0.60em;">=</span>
    </h1>
    <div id="notReally" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Not reeaaaaally:</h2>
        <span id="actually"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="number" class="answerInput"><br>
    <button class="2btn btn-large btn-success checkAnswer" href="#">Next</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    function biggestNumber() {
        return Math.max.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    $("#theChallenge").submit(function() {
        first = $(".first").text();
        second = $(".second").text();
        correctAnswer = parseInt($(".first").text()) * parseInt($(".second").text()); //parseInt = omvandla text till siffra.. och slå ihop de två alternativen!  och detta är då vårt rätta svar        
        theAnswer = $(".answerInput").val() //Vad har användaren skrivit in för svar?
        alert('first' + first);

        //Check if answer is correct
        if (theAnswer == correctAnswer) {
            //Create new numbers
            var randomNum = 1 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12); /* Pick random number between 1 and 12 */
            $('.first').text(randomNum);
            var randomNum = 1 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12); /* Pick random number between 1 and 12 */
            $('.second').text(randomNum);
        } else {
            //Show the person doing the test that
            $("#notReally").slideDown('fast');
            $("h1").slideUp('medium');

            biggestNumber = biggestNumber(first, second); //en funktion som är inlagd längre upp!!
            if (biggestNumber == first) { //Om största numret = första numret, då är det, det andra numret vi vill stapla upp, annars är det ju första siffran vi vill stapla upp "största siffran antalet gånger".
                theOtherNumber = second;
            } else {
                theOtherNumber = first;
            }
            staplaUpp = theOtherNumber; //Börja med att lägga in den mindre siffran en gång först, och sedan för varje till  " +siffran "
            for (var i = 0; i < biggestNumber - 1; i++) { //För varje antal det finns av den mindre siffran, stapla upp den med plus emellan!
                staplaUpp = staplaUpp + '<span style="margin:0 0.2em;">+</span>' + theOtherNumber;
            }
            $("#actually").append(staplaUpp);

        }

        $(".answerInput").val('');
        alert('first' + first);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: why not return false in else ?

Comment: I tried that now, still same problem

Comment: Now it works really well! :) Feel free to tell children learning the timestable to use it for drilling practice  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the form failing on the second submit is an indication that there was an error in your javascript event handler that prevented it from returning false.  To debug these, it is useful to use the javascript console in your browser with the option to preserve the log information when navigating between pages.  ( this option is called `Preserve Log upon Navigation` in the webkit debugger ).  Using this technique, I found:

```
Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function skolresurser.se:137
(anonymous function)
```

Looking at that section of code I can see the problem is here:

```
biggestNumber = biggestNumber(first,second); //en funktion som är inlagd längre upp!!
```

When you assign `biggestNumber` to the return value of itself, you overwrite the function `biggestNumber` with the number `biggestNumber`.  Then, the second time you click the submit button, your code fails.

Instead, you should be assigning that return value to a different variable:

```
     var bigNum = biggestNumber(first,second); //en funktion som är inlagd längre upp!!
       if(bigNum==first){ //Om största numret = första numret, då är det, det andra numret vi vill stapla upp, annars är det ju första siffran vi vill stapla upp "största siffran antalet gånger".
        theOtherNumber=second; 
       }else{
        theOtherNumber=first; 
       }
      staplaUpp = theOtherNumber;  //Börja med att lägga in den mindre siffran en gång först, och sedan för varje till  " +siffran "

       for(var i = 0; i < bigNum-1; i++) { //För varje antal det finns av den mindre siffran, stapla upp den med plus emellan!
            staplaUpp = staplaUpp + '<span style="margin:0 0.2em;">+</span>'+theOtherNumber;
        }
       $("#actually").append(staplaUpp);
```

Then your `biggestNumber` function is still a `function` the next time it's called.

Comment: same finding here, but i solved it using  just `var biggestNumber = biggestNumber(first,second)`

Comment: ahh I could still use the same name as long as I define it as a variable. Cool didn't know. I guess it's better if I do change the name though to keep the apart easier. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

no need to return false. this -(theAnswer==correctAnswer) is already false and the script knows that.. so remove the line return false.

Comment: if i remove the return false it reloads the page even if answer is correct, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to `prevetDeafult` on whole submit action, also the problem with redefine of biggestNumber, i solved redefine, using localising variable:

```
$(function() {
    function biggestNumber() {
        return Math.max.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    $("#theChallenge").submit(function(e) {


        e.preventDefault();  //<--HERE


        first = $(".first").text();
        second = $(".second").text();
        correctAnswer = parseInt($(".first").text()) * parseInt($(".second").text()); //parseInt = omvandla text till siffra.. och slå ihop de två alternativen!  och detta är då vårt rätta svar
        theAnswer = $(".answerInput").val() //Vad har användaren skrivit in för svar?

        //Check if answer is correct
        if (theAnswer == correctAnswer) {
            //Create new numbers
            var randomNum = 1 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12); /* Pick random number between 1 and 12 */
            $('.first').text(randomNum);
            var randomNum = 1 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12); /* Pick random number between 1 and 12 */
            $('.second').text(randomNum);
        } else {
            //Show the person doing the test that
            $("#notReally").slideDown('fast');
            $("h1").slideUp('medium');


            var biggestNumber = biggestNumber(first, second); //en funktion som är inlagd längre upp!! 
            //^--HERE


            if (biggestNumber == first) { //Om största numret = första numret, då är det, det andra numret vi vill stapla upp, annars är det ju första siffran vi vill stapla upp "största siffran antalet gånger".
                theOtherNumber = second;
            } else {
                theOtherNumber = first;
            }
            staplaUpp = theOtherNumber; //Börja med att lägga in den mindre siffran en gång först, och sedan för varje till  " +siffran "
            for (var i = 0; i < biggestNumber - 1; i++) { //För varje antal det finns av den mindre siffran, stapla upp den med plus emellan!
                staplaUpp = staplaUpp + '<span style="margin:0 0.2em;">+</span>' + theOtherNumber;
            }
            $("#actually").append(staplaUpp);

        }

        $(".answerInput").val('');
        alert('first' + first);
        return false;
    });


});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tWEY6/2/)